# Cannot PING domain name registered when configuring Azure Domain Services

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, domainservices

So I'm using Azure domain services with a DNS name of "hde.mydomain.com" (that's not the actual domain).  This was successfully created.  I can ping the DNS servers that were created as part of this domain but I cannot PING the domain itself using "hde.mydomain.com".  I have not added "mydomain.com" as a custom domain in Azure Active directory because this custom domain is already being used as a custom domain in office 365 (it complains that I need to remove it before adding it to the Azure active directory custom domain names).

So the question is this...when using a non "on-microsoft" DNS name when configuring domain services, like I chose to do, does that require the root part of that DNS name be added as a custom domain name in Azure Active directory or should I be able to use whatever DNS name I want without a custom domain and have it be pingable from servers that I would like to domain join from?

Comment: How long has it been since you created the domain? It can take IIRC up to 24 hours for the name to propagate through the internet's many nameservers.

Comment: Looks like it finally started resolving.  Didn't know the lag was there for resolving internal network IP addresses, but it's up now after a day.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can try pinging the Virtual IP address and see if it reaches. Sometimes it's just finicky about the name.

Also, check your NSG, firewall, and file sharing settings to ensure nothing is blocking this.

See this question to see if the insights here are helpful: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/2ba26393-936d-47f6-90e7-7601c268060f/vm-unable-to-ping-azure-ad-domain-services-this-morning-working-fine-last-night?forum=WAVirtualMachinesforWindows

Comment: I actually couldn't see what the virtual IP address was, but after DNS resolved, I can see that it was actually the same IP address as the first DNS server.  Since this is an internal DNS name (not something that is publicly registered), can you explain why it took over a day for that custom DNS name to be reachable?